# Bash : Syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

i am a beginner to Linux stuffs. Following some tutorial I used the following command, that split my zinc.mol2 into 1000 files named tmp.

```
cat zinc.mol2 | csplit -ftmp -n4 -ks - '%^@.TRIPOS.MOLECULE%' '/^@.TRIPOS.MOLECULE/' '{*}'
```

Now I have to use the following script, as per tutorial. When I use the first part `foreach f (tmp*)`, I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

Can some one guide me, how to successfully run the following script?

```
# Rename the tmp file according to ZINC identifier
# Here the outline of how we do this:
#    1. extract ZINCn8 from the tmpNNNN file and set to variable
#    2. if the Zn8.mol2 file does not exist, the rename the tmpNNNN file

foreach f (tmp*)
echo $f
set zid = `grep ZINC $f`
if !(-e "$zid".mol2) then
set filename = "$zid".mol2
else foreach n (`seq -w 1 99`)
if !(-e "$zid"_"$n".mol2) then
set filename = "$zid"_"$n".mol2
break
endif
end
endif
mv -v $f $filename
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run `csh` commands in `bash`

Comment: Have you considered using Python instead?

Comment: Also posted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294386/ .

Comment: [please don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/310919)

Answer (score 3):

The code you are trying to run appears to be in the syntax of the C-shell, rather than the Bourne family of shells.

You can either install and use a C-shell - for example, the `tcsh` package

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh

csh
```

or convert the code into its `bash` equivalent: the following is untested since I don't have access to your input file, but should be close

```
for f in tmp*; do
  echo "$f"

  zid="$(grep ZINC "$f")"
  if [ -e "${zid}.mol2" ]; then
    filename="${zid}.mol2"
  else
    for n in {01..99}; do
      if [ -e "${zid}_${n}.mol2" ]; then
        filename="${zid}_${n}.mol2"
        break;
      fi
    done
  fi

  mv -v "$f" "$filename"

done
```